# Ventilation Vents for Closet with Furnace and Hot Water Heater

Tags: ventilation

I have a closet with a Furnace and Hot water heater. The closest has a Luver door, I want to replace with a regular closet door. I have (2) 8 x 15 Vents which pull air into that room from my basement living area. My question is are these adequate enough to supply the air needed once I put a regular door on the closet?? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are the furnace and the water heater gas appliances ?

Comment: Both furnace and Hot water heater are gas.